# A port is requesting an older version of clang - will a newer one work?

Tags: macports

I'm attempting to install neovim.

When I run `sudo port install neovim`, it proceeds to install clang-3.7. However, `port rdeps neovim` doesn't show clang-3.7 as a dependency.

So does this mean that neither neovim nor any of its dependencies require clang-3.7? If so, then What's causing the install of clang-3.7?

I have clang-4.0 and clang-5.0 installed. Will these work?

Comment: What does the log show. I just installed neovim and don't have clang installed

Comment: It's not installing a binary package, it's trying to compile something.  That's why it wants clang.  It should be telling you what it's trying to install.

Comment: @Mark The first section in the log where clang-3.7 is mentioned can be found here -- https://pastebin.com/raw/99uvGaj9 . Also, Clang-3.7 failed to build -- https://pastebin.com/raw/bnX1BSRQ .

Comment: On Lion.  That would have been useful to know.

Comment: I don't believe that it should matter. Macports has many versions of clang and other compilers available for Lion. I have Clang-4.0 and Clang-5.0

Comment: It matters what os as for old ones you need to install extra compilers and c++ libraries

Comment: I would ask this on the macports mailing list especially as it is compiling stuff not just getting the binaries

Comment: I doubt MacPorts is providing binary packages for Lion (if they ever did), so yes, if you have the Lion MacPorts installed, I imagine it IS going to want to compile everything, and with an old compiler too.